# Calculate number of possibilites

Tags: math

I want to build a random and unique strings using 3 random chars from these chars-bank:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`

How can I calculate the unique (without repetitions) combinations?

Comment: (Number of possible characters)^3

Comment: @cmorrissey actually its `238328`. OP didn't specify that literals are unique within random string.

Comment: maybe fun? [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: [combinations and permutations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 62^3 = 238,328 with repetitions
- 62 x 61 x 60 = 226,920 without

Comment: not sure I understood your answer, and what if I want a length of 4? you just do 62x61x60x59.. ?

Comment: exactly ! But I don't know why you put a "php" tag on your question, this is more "mathematics"